# Correct way to unload a user control in code

Tags: c#, wpf

My application loads an appropriate UserControl onto the canvas depending on some built in logic.

The control on occasion need to be replaced by another UserControl.

To unload the control in code I detached it from it's parent, however I noticed (via the debug window) the processes within the control were still active.

I then subscribed to the Unloaded event and stopped the timers which were running in the user control when the event was raised.

Is this the correct way to handle this? How should I ensure this instance of the UserControl is gone and not still working away in the background?

**How I'm loading the UserControl**

```
 var arp = new CisDeparturesPanel(_config.CrsCode);
                        PanelContainer.Children.Add(arp);
                        _panel = arp;
```

**How I'm detaching the UserControl**

```
 var element = _panel as CisDeparturesPanel;
            PanelContainer.Children.Remove(element);
            _panel = null;
```

**UnLoaded Event Handler**

```
private void CisDeparturesPanel_OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Unloaded");

            _cacheReadTimer.Stop();
            _cacheReadTimer.Dispose();

            _displaySwitchTimer.Stop();
            _displaySwitchTimer.Dispose();

            _timeNowTimer.Stop();
            _timeNowTimer.Dispose();

            _updateCacheFromLiveData.Stop();
            _updateCacheFromLiveData.Dispose();

        }
```

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I too see that removing Children does not cause Unloaded to be fired.

Answer (score 1):

In silverlight you can add an empty finalizer to object you want to check:

```
public ~ClassToCheck()
{} // set breakpoint here
```

And invoke `GC.Collect();` when you want to check if it's already fully unloaded.

It should be similar in wpf.

Comment: Thanks for the input, the Destructor is only called when I close the application. It's closing the control alone I'm struggling with.

Comment: Are you sure you added finalizer to your `UserControl`? Then you should easily check if it's properly unloaded. Look for static references in your `UserControl` and detach them or dispose. Remember that your control can only be disposed when it cannot be accessed from any other part of your application.